# Are Kingston DDR3 1333mhz and Crucial DDR3 1600mhz 2GB RAM sticks compatible?

Tags: memory, ddr3, voltage

I have 2 crucial sticks in my ASUS P8Z68-V LX atm. I'd like to go to 8GB and wanted to know if the lower voltage Kingston sticks would be compatible?

Also I feel I should point out the Kingston RAM is half the height of the Crucial sticks. Not sure why, but would this be an issue?

Comment: All the sticks have to run at the same voltage.

Comment: is this BIOS configurable?

Comment: DDR3 is DDR3.  Faster memory will run at the slowest frequency, if slower memory is installed, DDR3 is DDR3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use two types of DDR3 in the same motherboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/917497/can-i-use-two-types-of-ddr3-in-the-same-motherboard)

Comment: @DavidPostill this is more specific though.

Answer (score 1):

When you match up different ram kits, make sure that they can run at the same timings, or CAS latency. RAM timings will be expressed in a format such as 9-9-9-24. To keep it easy, choose to use the higher timings if the kits aren't the same latency.

Setting RAM to higher voltages than the kit specifies can increase the temperature of the RAM module. Keep voltages set as close to spec as possible, unless you have a good reason.

RAM height is a non-issue unless it gets in the way of a CPU heatsink or something.

Comment: The older Kingston is 9-9-9-24, the newer Crucial is 11-11-11-28

Comment: Unless your BIOS will let you set the timings per-stick, use the crucial timings for your PC.

Answer (score 1):

They are generally compatible.  That is the benefit to them being DDR3.

However, note the word "generally".

The reports I've heard is that compatibility can vary.  Sometimes, running RAM of different speeds doesn't work well.  If it doesn't work well in one system, it might work okay in a different system.  The reasons have to do with some very specific details about the motherboards and RAM chips.  These differences might not always be documented.  Sometimes the only way to really know is to try it.  If things don't work well, your system is likely to work extremely slowly, but you're not likely to have a bunch of unexpected/undetected data corruption.  If this essentially breaks the ability for your system to be re-usable, the way to resolve is as easy as pulling out one of the RAM chip types.

That said, it's often recommended that you don't purchase RAM sticks that are different, just hoping for the best.  (But if you have them, you could try them.)

When purchasing, general recommendations include matching the CAS values, matching the overall speeds, matching the manufacturer, matching the model number, or even buying all the RAM in one batch so you are matching the same manufacturing run.  The more of these that you can match, the better your chances are.

So if you have Crucial, try to stick with Crucial (if you're wanting to have that additional RAM in your computer at the same time), and order the same model number.  Alternatively, if you're just trying to get higher-capacity RAM chips, the safe approach is to get enough higher capacity RAM chips to fill your slots.  If you can only afford enough higher capacity RAM chips to fill some slots, go ahead and do that.  Then, you can try using the Crucial as well (mixing RAM sticks), but be prepared ahead of time for the possibility that it won't work well.

Yes, following these recommendations may involve spending more money, or leaving perfectly functional RAM chips unused.  Those are the unideal characteristics of this situation that is forced upon us since incompatibilities do exist.  So, either follow the recommendations for the safest approaches, or be prepared to deal with the possibility of things not working well.

Note: The last time I checked, Crucial did have the better reputation regarding quality (while Kingston did have the reputation of frequently having lower priced options).  Going strictly for quality, Crucial may have been the top name, followed by Corsair (though certainly some people would have differing opinions, flipping those two.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are all compatible. Lower voltages just means that they can run with less but not necessarily have to.

Comment: How do I specify in the BIOS that they need to run at 1.5V? Do I need to do this?

Comment: You do not need to specify that manually. Your mainboard will all run them on the same voltage. If you want you can specify it. Check your BIOS for overclocking settings and look for RAM Voltage somewhere. You can also try to undervolt all RAM and get it to run. This will take some time in testing however.